# Select all newline in a text doc except the ones with a particular match

Tags: regex

I want to replace all that matches `\n`, except the `\n` that is followed by `"some-digit"`

I am able to individually match both. For example:
I can get all newline by using `\n`. And I can get all the digits in quotes that is followed by a newline by using `\n\"\d+\"`. However, how can I replace all `\n` but skip this `\n\"\d+\"`.

Is there a way for us to write regex match, conditionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using the below regex pattern:

```
\n+(?!\"\d+\”)
```